# Apache SocketFactory compatible with java.net SocketFactory?

Tags: java, solr, https, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm making a request using Apache's DefaultHttpClient and I need to override the SSL call so that I can attach a custom SSLSocketFactory (essentially a client cert) to it. To do this, I create a new custom scheme and connection manager and pass them over at httpClient creation:

```
...
new Scheme("https", 443, thirdPartySocketFactory);
...
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm);
...
```

The `thirdPartySocketFactory` passed at Scheme creation is the important part here. As the name suggests, it comes from a third party library that automatically handles mutual cert authentication with a JBoss server. I.e., it attaches a client cert + password to each outbound request.

The call itself is also made from a JBoss server (I'm actually hosting SOLR on it which is why the Apache call is necessary in the first place).

**Problem** is, the `thirdPartySocketFactory` object is of the type `javax.net.SocketFactory`, not `org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory` which the Apache Scheme requires (see [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html)).

**Question**: Is there any way to solve this nicely via some sort of wrapper? I thought the Apache SocketFactory would inherit from the javax.net one in some way but it doesn't look like it.

Alternatively, I can create a truely custom Apache SSLSocketFactory (see [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html)), complete with truststore etc, but I really don't want to go down route until the other option is exhausted. Main reason being, the `thirdPartySocketFactory` method is tried and tested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `SSLSocketFactory#SSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory socketfactory, X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier)` since version 4.2. This constructor serves as a adapter for any arbitrary JSSE SSLSocketFactory implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that as the constructor doc didn't contain the package name (although it does link to the javadoc).